# Wait until all images on the page have been loaded

Tags: javascript

I would like to wait until no more images are downloading:

```js
const waitForImages = async () => {
  const cleanupHandler = new Set();
  const images = document.querySelectorAll("img");
  console.log("wait for images", images.length);
  await Promise.all(
    Array.from(images).map((image) =>
      new Promise<void>((resolve) => {
        if (image.complete) {
          return resolve();
        }

        const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
          console.log(image, "timed out");
          resolve();
        }, 500);
        const cleanup = () => {
          clearTimeout(timeout);
          image.removeEventListener("load", imageLoadingDone);
          image.removeEventListener("error", imageLoadingDone);
          cleanupHandler.delete(cleanup);
        };
        cleanupHandler.add(cleanup);
        const imageLoadingDone = () => {
          console.log(image, "done");
          cleanup();
          resolve();
        };
        image.addEventListener("load", imageLoadingDone);
        image.addEventListener("error", imageLoadingDone);
      })
    )
  );
  console.log("all images loaded");
  cleanupHandler.forEach((cleanup) => cleanup());
}
```

The code works very well.
Unfortunately as soon as there is a hidden `<img loading="lazy">` on the page the `load` event is never fired. (see [HTML Image Element loading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/loading))

Is there any way to skip those `loading="lazy"` images which don't start their download?

Comment: Maybe you can filter the `document.querySelectorAll("img")` result on the lazy loading property? (only add images to the array that do not have that property)

Comment: Post the code for `<img loading="lazy">`

Comment: There is no code for `<img loading=lazy` see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/loading

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Array.from(images).filter((image) => image.loading !== "lazy").map(...)
```

Comment: This will also skip images which are downloaded by the browser

Comment: @jantimon I'm confused by the comment. The default value of `loading` is `"eager"`, which would not be filtered out here. Only images which explicitly have their `loading` properties set to `"lazy"` would be removed from the array. You could also use `document.querySelectorAll('img:not(loading), img:not([loading="lazy"])')` if you were only concerned with images whose loading attributes had been set in HTML. Of course, neither of these is a live collection, but the original code does not appear concerned with that either.

Comment: Sorry - maybe I should add that better to the question.. I want to wait for all eager loading images and all lazy loading images (like `<img loading="lazy") which the browser is currently downloading.. But I don't want to wait for lazy images which the browser did not start downloading

Comment: @jantimon "_as soon as there is a **hidden** `<img loading="lazy">`_" is the main challenge. And this can be solved with the filter method suggested. You should only filter the ones having `image.loading !== "lazy"` and `image.style.display !== "none"` (or whatever method you use to hide the elements).

Comment: Some are hidden because of `overview: hidden` some are `display:none` some are outside the current viewport ... 

I am looking for a browser API which helps me to identify images which are being downloaded

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution however I still hope there is a less complicated one:

```
/**
 * Wait until all images are downloaded and encoded.
 */
export const waitForImages = async () => {
  // Get only images in view - this is a Workaround for lazy loading images
  const images = Array.from(await getAllImagesIntersectingViewport());
  const imageLoadPromisses = Array.from(images).map(
    (image) =>
      new Promise<void>((resolve) => {
        if (image.complete) {
          return resolve();
        }
        // fallback timeout to prevent freezing the entire test
        const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
          console.log("timeout", image);
          resolve();
        }, 2000);
        const cleanup = () => {
          clearTimeout(timeout);
          image.removeEventListener("load", imageLoadingDone);
          image.removeEventListener("error", imageLoadingDone);
        };
        const imageLoadingDone = () => {
          cleanup();
          image
            .decode()
            .catch(() => {
              /* ignore decoding erros */
            })
            .then(resolve);
        };
        image.addEventListener("load", imageLoadingDone);
        image.addEventListener("error", imageLoadingDone);
      })
  );
  // wait until all images are loaded
  await Promise.all(imageLoadPromisses);
  return images;
};

/**
 * Get all images that are currently inside the viewport
 */
const getAllImagesIntersectingViewport = async () => {
  const intersectingImages = new Set<HTMLImageElement>();
  const images = document.querySelectorAll("img");
  if (images.length) {
    let observer: IntersectionObserver | undefined;
    await new Promise<void>((resolve) => {
      const imageObserver = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
        entries.forEach((entry) => {
          if (
            entry.isIntersecting &&
            entry.target instanceof HTMLImageElement
          ) {
            intersectingImages.add(entry.target);
          }
        });
        resolve();
      });
      observer = imageObserver;
      images.forEach((image) => imageObserver.observe(image));
    });
    if (observer) {
      observer.disconnect();
    }
  }
  return intersectingImages;
};
```

Comment: This effectively bypasses the benefits of `loading="lazy"`, but if it is intersecting the viewport it should technically already be loading.

Comment: Why would it bypass something?
It gets all images in the current viewport and waits for them to be done loading.

Comment: Just looking at MDN it states `Defers loading the image until it reaches a calculated distance from the viewport, as defined by the browser`, so as defined by the browser is being bypassed because as far as I know there is no API exposed to integrate with the browsers underlying heuristic. You may be downloading `lazy` images too soon or not catching one's that have begun downloading while not in viewport.

Comment: If you check the [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#attr-img-loading) you get more details on how this might bypass the `lazy` aspects. For instance, lazy images in the viewport on page load aren't downloaded until layout is known, unlike `eager` images in viewport. Moreover, the implementation-defined [rootMargin](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/urls-and-fetching.html#lazy-load-root-margin) for the IO observing the `lazy` image is based on things like scroll speed, network conditions, etc. Maybe this doesn't matter for your use case though.

Comment: "You may be downloading lazy images too soon" why would I download them - I am only waiting for them.

Answer (score 0):

This idea is so simple that I may have misunderstood the problem (apologies if so).

The idea is to limit your query selector to those images lacking the `loading="lazy"` attribute by directly substituting the `"img"` selector in your function with:

```
"img:not([loading='lazy'])"
```

The following snippet contains seven image elements, four of which have `loading="lazy"` attributes. The html collection referenced using the above selector contains 3 items, corresponding to the 3 'normal' image elements.

```js
const images = document.querySelectorAll("img:not([loading='lazy'])");

    console.log(images.length);
```

```html
    <img src="path/1.png" loading="lazy" />

    <img src="path/2.png"  />

    <img src="path/3.png" loading="lazy" />

    <img src="path/4.png"  />

    <img src="path/5.png"  />

    <img src="path/6.png" loading="lazy" />

    <img src="path/7.png" loading="lazy" />
```

Comment: `which do not start their download` is the tricky part. How do you know the browser has not initiated the download of one of the lazy images based on whatever heuristic is in play?

Comment: @ morganney, I see, yes. I thought it was probably not as simple as I'd first thought. Thanks for pointing that out. (in anycase it seems images with loading attributes set to lazy don't count for the normal load event anyway).

Answer (score 0):

grabbed from [here](https://www.seancdavis.com/posts/wait-until-all-images-loaded/)

> we're going to clone every image behind the scenes (i.e. without rendering it to the DOM) and then listen for it to be loaded. Here's what the new script might look like:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  // Images loaded is zero because we're going to process a new set of images.
  var imagesLoaded = 0;
  // Total images is still the total number of <img> elements on the page.
  var totalImages = $("img").length;

  // Step through each image in the DOM, clone it, attach an onload event
  // listener, then set its source to the source of the original image. When
  // that new image has loaded, fire the imageLoaded() callback.
  $("img").each(function (idx, img) {
    $("<img>").on("load", imageLoaded).attr("src", $(img).attr("src"));
  });

  // Do exactly as we had before -- increment the loaded count and if all are
  // loaded, call the allImagesLoaded() function.
  function imageLoaded() {
    imagesLoaded++;
    if (imagesLoaded == totalImages) {
      allImagesLoaded();
    }
  }

  function allImagesLoaded() {
    console.log("ALL IMAGES LOADED");
  }
});
```

Comment: doesn't work anymore in 2022 because images might use native lazy loading

Answer (score 0):

If want just to skip them, you can simple filter your images by loading property

```
const images = document.querySelectorAll("img").filter(img => img.loading !== "lazy");
```

In that way your code wouldn't wait for lazy images. And in case if you want all images to be downloaded, you can programmatically set loading to "auto", but I believe that it's not your case

Comment: doesn't work anymore in 2022 because images might use native lazy loading